# jquery to show popup in salesforce

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
  <apex:form >
  <script>
  function showSimpleDialog(){    
   var sd = new SimpleDialog("Test"+Dialogs.getNextId(), false);    
   sd.setTitle("Test Pop up");   
   sd.createDialog();   
   window.parent.sd = sd;   
   sd.setContentInnerHTML("<p align='center'><img src='/img/msg_icons/warning32.png' style='margin:0 5px;'/></p><p align='center'>This is awesome!</p><p align='center'><br /><button class='btn' onclick='window.parent.sd.hide(); return false;'>cancel</button></p>");    
   sd.show();   
 }  
 </script> 
  <apex:pageBlock >
  <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
  <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!Account.BillingCity}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!Account.BillingPostalCode}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Phone}"/>
  <apex:commandButton value="save" onfocus="showSimpleDialog();"/>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

i dnt want to use controller,please suggest me what to do?!i have to use jquery.if i place my cursor in phone field,then popup should be shown.thanks advance

Comment: Where is the save button present? Is it custom VF page?

Comment: yes ,,itis vf page,but i wanted to show popup when i click on phone field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get it displayed on phone field, `use onfocus()` event of phone field.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}';
    </script>
    <script src="../../soap/ajax/38.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
  <apex:form >
  <script>
        function showSimpleDialog(){    
            var sd = new SimpleDialog("Test"+Dialogs.getNextId(), false);
            sd.setTitle("Test Pop up");   
            sd.createDialog(); 
            sd.setWidth(350);
            window.parent.sd = sd;   
            sd.setContentInnerHTML("<p align='center'><img src='/img/msg_icons/warning32.png' style='margin:0 5px;'/></p><p align='center'>This is awesome!</p><p align='center'><br /><button class='btn' onclick='window.parent.sd.hide(); return false;'>cancel</button></p>");    
            sd.show();   
        }
 </script> 
  <apex:pageBlock >
  <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
  <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!Account.BillingCity}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!Account.BillingPostalCode}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Phone}" onfocus="showSimpleDialog();"/>
  <apex:commandButton value="save"/>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Comment: If the fix worked, please mark it as answer so others can benefi.